# Select to javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save all my options as a javaScript Array

Html

```
 <select id="mySelect">
  <option value="0"> option 2 </option>
  <option value="0"> option 3 </option>
  <option value="0"> option 4 </option>
  <option value="0"> option 5 </option>
 </select>
```

Js

```
 $select = $("#mySelect");
 $options = $select.find("option");

 for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++ ) {
  alert($options[i].val()); 
}
```

`alert($options[i].val());` won't work , I got `$options[i].val() is not a function`

Comment: What are you trying to store, the values or the text?

Comment: options are an array in the select DOM object, not a separate dom entity of their own for what you're doing. try `$select.options[i].val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because when you do `$options[i]` you don't get a jquery object, you get an element. use `value`:

```
 $select = $("#mySelect");
 $options = $select.find("option");

 for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++ ) {
  alert($options[i].value); 
}
```

If you want a jquery object, you can use `.eq()` instead... like this:

```
 $select = $("#mySelect");
 $options = $select.find("option");

 for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++ ) {
  alert($options.eq(i).val()); 
}
```

Either way will work fine, although the second will create a jquery object which is not necessary in this case.
http://jsfiddle.net/pnkpF/
http://jsfiddle.net/pnkpF/1/

Comment: +1 for `.eq` over `$($options[i])` (which someone else had in their answer)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery:

```
var arr = $('#mySelect option').map(function(){
              return this.value;
          }).get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A5Mdz/).

The reason that `options[i].val()` failed is that `options[i]` is a native DOM node, not a jQuery object.

If you'd like to do the same with plain JavaScript:

```
var opts = document.getElementById('mySelect').getElementsByTagName('option'),
    arr = [];
for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(opts[i].value);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A5Mdz/1/).

Or, for more up-to-date browsers:

```
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#mySelect option'),
    arr = [];
for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(opts[i].value);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A5Mdz/2/).

And in slightly *more* modern browsers:

```
var arr = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#mySelect option'), function(a){
    return a.value;
});

console.log(arr);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A5Mdz/5/).

Also, if you'd like to take both the `value` *and* the text-content from the `option`s (as a simple demo, using the second code-sample from above as the basis):

```
var opts = document.getElementById('mySelect').getElementsByTagName('option'),
    arr = [], tmp;
for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) {
    tmp = opts[i];
    arr.push({'value' : tmp.value, 'content' : (tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText)})
}

console.log(arr);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A5Mdz/4/).

References:

- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`map()` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Answer (score 3):

`val` is not the correct attribute for the `option` tag. Use `value` instead:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="0"> option 2 </option>
  <option value="0"> option 3 </option>
  <option value="0"> option 4 </option>
  <option value="0"> option 5 </option>
</select>
```

Also, if you select [i] from a jQuery array, you get the raw HTML element. Wrap it in jQuery again to have access to functions like .val():

```
$select = $("#mySelect");
$options = $select.find("option");

for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++ ) {
  alert($($options[i]).val()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Array**

```
var options = [];

$("#mySelect option").each(function() {
  options.push($(this).val());
});
```

`options` will look like this:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0']
```

**Option 2: Object**

If you want to save the `text` within the `<option>` (e.g. `option 2` or `option 3`) then you should probably store this in a Javascript object rather than an array. Take a look at this:

```
var options = {};

$("#mySelect option").each(function() {
  options[$(this).html()] = $(this).val();
});
```

`options` will look like this:

```
{
  ' option 2 ': '0',
  ' option 3 ': '0',
  ' option 4 ': '0',
  ' option 5 ': '0'
}
```